# Get this value by class on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have form and jquery for get value `this` by class

```js
function sendModel(el){
var id_model = $(el).class('id_model');
  alert(id_model);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name='id_model' class='id_model' value='M001'>
  
  <button onclick='sendModel(this)'> send </button>
  
  </form>
```

how to show alert with `id_model` value ??thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Submit form

```js
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var id_model = $('.id_model').val();
  alert(id_model);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input name='id_model' class='id_model' value='M001'>
  
  <button type="submit"> send </button>
  
  </form>
```

#### Your way

```js
function sendModel(){
  var id_model = $('.id_model').val();
  alert(id_model);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name='id_model' class='id_model' value='M001'>
  
  <button onclick='sendModel()'> send </button>
  
  </form>
```

Comment: in form is many `input` and i just get one input (`id_model`) . so i use onclick to get `id_model` . in form above is in `modals one` and i pass `id_model` to `modals two`. how i do this ?

Comment: My second answer does not use `submit` but `onclick`, so you have the value. What do you mean by > pass `id_model` to `modals two` ? An other input ?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try this?

```
var id_model = $('.id_model');

alert(id_model.attr('value'))
```

Comment: no, in form above is modals one, and i want to send `id_model` to modals two by onclick